# is there any PostgreSQL loader like Oracle has?

Tags: postgresql

how to use copy statement in postgresql to load data from a text file where the file has an escape character as a delimiter into a postgresql table?

Is there any otherway of loading data from textfile into a PostgreSQL table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pg loader emulates oracles sql loader:

http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgloader/

pg bulkload is used to load lots of data in an otherwise offline db.  Useful for large data warehouses, fast, and somewhat dangerous and quirky:

http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should use [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) with the `DELIMITER 'xx'` option. You probably need to play around a little bit to get it right, but the docs give a pretty good information about what to do with each option available to the command.

Comment: the postgresql document doesn't list the valid delimiters. But in my case i have to use vertical tab or escape character as the delimiter. But i tried to use these two characters but postgresql is giving error saying `^v` (which is a vertical tab ) is not a single byte character. Can anybody suggest how to overcome this? i Have to use escape or vertical tab as a delimiter at any cost.